# class which attribute reference object type is same class

Tags: c#, .net, class, types, attributes

I want to analyse a source code which give me for evolution.
In this code, I have a class which attribute type is that the same type of this same class.

I don't understand what is the function of this development. The compiler is OK but there is a infinity reference in this code no ?

*Example:*

```
public sealed class CachingServiceLocator : IDisposable
{

    private Hashtable cache; /// Le cache des références vers les services métiers
    private static volatile CachingServiceLocator me; /// L'unique instance du Service Locator

    /// Le constructeur statique
    static CachingServiceLocator()
    {
        try
        {
            me = new CachingServiceLocator();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Impossible de créer le service locator...\nVeuillez accepter toutes nos excuses pour le désagrément occasionné..." , "Service Locator !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Can you give me to understand this development please.

Comment: nope, it's creating a new instance in the _static_ constructor, which will only run once.

Answer (score 2):

This is classic implementation of Singleton Pattern. In this way its made sure, only one object is created for this class type(for example logger, configuration classes generally are made singleton)

There are other things which you probably missed, like the instance constructor for this type must be private, the class it self is sealed etc.

So you can not do this

```
CachingServiceLocator  obj = new CachingServiceLocator() //not allowed

//to get the instance you have to do as following
CachingServiceLocator obj = CachingServiceLocator.me
```

[Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html)

Comment: Already I learn the design pattern singleton but he wasn't design like this (most complexe before). this implementation it's more basically. I understand that is the static constructor rule it must use for this situation.